# How to remove the $_GET variable after processing it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So I got a little problem. I'm currently learning how to handle laravel. I was okay until now. I`ve tried to create a small page. 4 Articles, 1 Basket, when I click a button, I just hand over the id and the name of the article via $_GET and put it into the basket. This is the controller i have for now:

```
class FileviewController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = "layouts.master";

    public function getIndex() {
        if(isset($_GET["article"])) {
            Session::push("basket.items", filter_var($_GET["article"]));
            $items = Session::all();
        }

        $articles = Article::with('manufacturer')->get();
    }
    $articles = Article::with('manufacturer')->get();
    $this->layout->content = View::make("article.index", array("items" => $items, "articles" => $articles));
}
```

At first ive tried to use `header()` and redirect him on the current page without the parameeter ... didnt work for some reason:

```
if(isset($_GET["article_id"])) {
    Session::push("basket.item_id", filter_var($_GET["article_id"]));
    Session::push("basket.item_name", filter_var($_GET["article_name"]));
    $items = Session::all();
    $articles = Article::with('manufacturer')->get();
    header('Location: http://10.36.155.40/laravel/public/article');
}
```

Didn't work out. Is there any other way to remove the variables from the URL after they have been processed? Because even if the user reloads, the variable is still there and will be added to the basket again. For obvious reasons, i have to avoid that.

I guess i just cant see the forest because of all the trees. Is there even an easier way to do that?

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just redirect them using Laravels Redirect facade.  Gone are the days of setting Location headers!  Full docs located [here](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects).  Here are a few examples:

```
return Redirect::to('/');

return Redirect::route('my.named.route');

return Redirect::back()->with('errorMessage', 'Get out of here!');
```

Comment: My lifesaver. I looked through the docs but somehow i must have overlooked that thing. Thanks a lot!